# Trying to make a launcher to launch Korganizer to work in a time zone different from system time zone. Works under KDE but not in Gnome or mate

Tags: gnome, kde, launcher, mate

Trying to make a launcher that works in Gnome/MATE

I have the following launcher text formatted for Gnome/MATE:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Version=1.0
Type=Application
Name=Korganizer 
Exec=TZ=US/Pacific /usr/bin/korganizer %U
Icon=korganizer
Path=
Terminal=true
StartupNotify=true
GenericName=Korganizer
```

There is no entry in the launcher creator GUI in MATE to specify that the launcher should launch in terminal. So I created the text file above which works for and works fine except for this:

```
Exec=TZ=US/Pacific korganizer %U
```

which is intended to launch Korganizer in the stated timezone regardless of the system time zone. The launcher only works in KDE desktop so long as "Terminal=true" is specified. In MATE, for example, I must enter "TZ=US/Pacific korganizer %U" into terminal for it to launch.  It will not launch from the desktop launcher in MATE or Gnome.

By adding the TZ= to this line, is it allows me to launch the calendar, fixed in a certain time zone, which is not the same as the system timezone. So it is as if Korganizer is running on a system in said timezone.

In the MATE or Gnome desktops, the launcher flat-out will not work, in this case. This, in spite of having designated Terminal=true in the launcher text file. Again the same command launches Korganizer, just fine, if entered into an actual terminal.

Answer (score 0):

I have found a solution that works by changing the line in the Desktop Launcher file(right-click the launcher and (open with) -edit the file with a text editor of your choice).

I changed the line, as an example below:

```
Exec=TZ=US/Pacific korganizer %U
```

To:

```
Exec=bash -c "TZ=US/Pacific korganizer %U"
```

...which now works flawlessly.

To use for other commands: Within the quotations, just replace the command that must be run in terminal shell, with your command, which is otherwise failing to launch by double-clinking the icon, but does launch when you enter it into an actual terminal. Remember to also assure that "terminal=true".